# problem with svg device, expression(), and unicode characters

Tags: r, svg, unicode

I am having difficulty using the svg device with math expressions and unicode (in this case, left- and right-quotes). This only occurs on my Windows 10 computer; my osx computer seems unaffected. Consider the following R code:

```
output = tempfile(fileext = ".svg")

svg(file = output)

plot(1, axes=FALSE, ty='n')

## Line A: 
mtext(side = 2, text = expression(paste("A")))
## Line B:
mtext(side = 3, text = expression(paste("“B")))
## Line C: 
mtext(side = 4, text = expression(paste("C")))

axis(1, at = par()$usr[1:2], lab = c("More", "Less"), tick = FALSE)

dev.off()

## Uncomment and run to open the SVG file to look at it 
# browseURL(output)
```

(Note the left-quote in Line B). Upon running Line C, I get

```
Error in mtext(side = 4, text = expression(paste("C"))) : 
  metric information not available for this device
```

- If I change the device to `png` I get the output I expect.
- If I comment out lines B and C, I get the output I expect (eg, the output from lines A and the axis)
- If I comment out only line C, I do not get the output I expect. Neither line B works, nor the axis. There appears to be something wrong with line B that causes everything later in the chunk to fail too.
- If I remove the `expression()` from line B, everything works as expected (including the unicode left-quote)
- If I change the font using `showtext` (see the issue for details: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1831) I have no problem.

This appears, then, to be an interaction between `svg`, `expression`, the default font, and unicode. But only on Windows 10. My OSX computer (see details below) does not have the issue.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reprex_0.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6    ps_1.3.2        digest_0.6.25   R6_2.4.1        evaluate_0.14   rlang_0.4.5     fs_1.4.1       
 [8] callr_3.4.3     whisker_0.4     rmarkdown_2.1   Cairo_1.5-12    tools_3.6.2     xfun_0.13       compiler_3.6.2 
[15] processx_3.4.2  clipr_0.7.0     htmltools_0.4.0 knitr_1.28.3
```

### OSX session info (no problem on this computer)

```
> xfun::session_info('knitr')
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4, RStudio 1.2.5031

Locale: en_GB.UTF-8 / en_GB.UTF-8 / en_GB.UTF-8 / C / en_GB.UTF-8 / en_GB.UTF-8

Package version:
  evaluate_0.14   glue_1.4.0      graphics_3.6.1  grDevices_3.6.1
  highr_0.8       knitr_1.28.3    magrittr_1.5    markdown_1.1   
  methods_3.6.1   mime_0.9        stats_3.6.1     stringi_1.4.6  
  stringr_1.4.0   tools_3.6.1     utils_3.6.1     xfun_0.12      
  yaml_2.2.1
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same problem on my 32-bit Windows work PC. It's a tricky error to track down, but I eventually found it is being thrown [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/graphics/src/graphics.c#L3404) in the `GMMathText` function of graphics.c. As you describe, it only seems to be a problem with `expression`s containing certain characters on some graphics devices. In particular, anything using Cairo on Windows seems to stub its toe at the same point.

After attempting several hacks to get around this, I found that the best solution is to simply use `bquote` instead of `expression`. This allows you to keep all of the `plotmath` functionality you get with `expression` without generating the error:

```
svg(output)
plot(1, axes=FALSE, ty='n')
mtext(side = 2, text = bquote("A"))
mtext(side = 3, text = bquote("“B"))
mtext(side = 4, text = bquote("C"))
axis(1, at = par()$usr[1:2], lab = c("More", "Less"), tick = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

Which gives the following SVG:

[image]

There is a nice overview of how to use `bquote` to generate your labels, including all the maths expressions you need [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/math-notation-for-r-plot-titles-expression-and-bquote/)

Comment: that does allow a compilation, but there is seemingly still a problem with math expressions. Try changing line to to `mtext(side = 3, text = bquote(alpha + "“B"))` and it fails again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking something of a guess here because I know nothing about R. However the local for your windows box is cp1252 which does not contain Unicode quotes but uses Microsoft's smart quotes.

You say it works in OS-X which looking at your session info is set up to use UTF-8.

I'm assuming that your program file is saved as UTF-8.